# Flexible system call in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm working on a [Sidekiq](http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/) worker that's sole purpose is to make several long-running system calls. I have the following requirements:

- Able to set environment variables
- Real-time output (stdout, stderr) stream
- Block thread until finished
- Get exit code
- Thread-safe, since sidekiq is multi-threaded (read: no `$?`)

I'm running on Ruby 1.9.2. Thanks for your input!

Comment: I realize it's old, and I may have to ask another question, but can you post some code? I'm trying to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$?` (as well as most other "magical" variables like `$1` etc.) is local to the current thread and thus using [`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Kernel.html#method-i-system) and `$?` is perfectly thread-safe and meets all your criteria.